# PHP pagination. End array has different number of values than the initial query

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, smarty, gammu

Up until now I've always been limiting my pages for any pagination simply using MySQL LIMIT. It's been performing well.

However... Now I've written an application that grabs the data from 3 separate MySQL tables, after that I'm using array_multisort() to sort them.

The main issue here is that it is used for SMS messages(gammu smsd). If I write a message consisting of let's say 900 characters - it is split to 7 entries in the database. It is split every 139 characters (the number might be different sometimes)
 Below code somewhat fixes this issue based on 'SequencePosition' field in the database.
So if I were to LIMIT it using MySQL I would have less results than I specified since MySQL has no idea what I'm doing with the data later.

I hope it makes sense to you guys.

How would you solve this issue? Can you think of a better way to do it? I mean- grabbing all the data from the table is rarely a good idea ;(

See PHP code below.

```
<?php    
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{

    if(isset($_GET['contact_number']) && ($_GET['contact_name']))
    {
        if (isset($_GET["page"]))
        {
            $page  = $_GET["page"];
        }
        else
        {
            $page = 1 ;
        }
        $gmessages_page = 30; //this is actually a static value, normally it resides in a config file
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $gmessages_page; 

        $contact_number = base64_decode($_GET['contact_number']);
        $contact_name = base64_decode($_GET['contact_name']);

        $query_inbox = "SELECT ReceivingDateTime, SenderNumber, TextDecoded FROM inbox WHERE SenderNumber='$contact_number' ORDER BY ReceivingDateTime";
        $query_sentitems = "SELECT SendingDateTime, DestinationNumber, TextDecoded, Status, SequencePosition FROM sentitems WHERE DestinationNumber='$contact_number' ORDER BY SendingDateTime";
        $query_outbox = "SELECT SendingDateTime, DestinationNumber, TextDecoded FROM outbox WHERE DestinationNumber='$contact_number' ORDER BY SendingDateTime";


        $result_inbox = $conn->query($query_inbox);
        $result_sentitems = $conn->query($query_sentitems);
        $result_outbox = $conn->query($query_outbox);

        if(!$result_inbox || !$result_sentitems || !$result_outbox)
        {
            die("Błąd połączenia z bazą (!RESULT)");
        }

        $rows_inbox = $result_inbox->num_rows;
        $rows_sentitems = $result_sentitems->num_rows;
        $rows_outbox = $result_outbox->num_rows;

        if($rows_inbox == 0 || $rows_sentitems == 0)
        {
            $conn->close();
        }

        //inbox

        $inbox_person = $contact_name;
        for($j = 0; $j < $rows_inbox ; ++$j)
        {
            $result_inbox->data_seek($j);
            $row_inbox = $result_inbox->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

            $inbox_date[] = $row_inbox[0];
            $inbox_number = $row_inbox[1];
            $inbox_text[] = $row_inbox[2];
            $sent_status[] = 0;
            $sent_sequence_position[] = 0;
            $inbox_type[] = 1;
        }

        for($j = 0; $j < $rows_sentitems ; ++$j)
        {
            $result_sentitems->data_seek($j);
            $row_sentitems = $result_sentitems->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

            if($row_sentitems[4] == 1)
            {
                $sent_sequence_position[] = $row_sentitems[4];
                $inbox_date[] = $row_sentitems[0];
                $inbox_text[] = $row_sentitems[2];
                $sent_status[] = $row_sentitems[3];
                $inbox_type[] = 2;                  
            }
            else
            {
                $inbox_text[sizeof($inbox_type) - 1] .= $row_sentitems[2];         
            }
        }


        for($j = 0; $j < $rows_outbox ; ++$j)
        {
            $result_outbox->data_seek($j);
            $row_outbox = $result_outbox->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
            $inbox_date[] = $row_outbox[0];
            $inbox_text[] = $row_outbox[2];
            $sent_status[] = "QueuedForSending";
            $inbox_type[] = 2;
        }
        $number_of_records = sizeof($inbox_date);
        $number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_records / $gmessages_page);   

        array_multisort($inbox_date, $inbox_text, $inbox_type, $sent_status, $sent_sequence_position);

        $smarty->assign("inbox_date", $inbox_date);
        $smarty->assign("inbox_text", $inbox_text);
        $smarty->assign("inbox_number", $inbox_number);
        $smarty->assign("inbox_person", $contact_name);
        $smarty->assign("inbox_type", $inbox_type);
        $smarty->assign("sent_status", $sent_status);
        $smarty->assign("start_from", $start_from);
        $smarty->assign("gmessages_page", $gmessages_page);
        $smarty->assign("number_of_pages", $number_of_pages);
        $smarty->assign("number_of_records", $number_of_records);
        $smarty->assign("sent_sequence_position", $sent_sequence_position);
        $smarty->assign("page", $page);

        //for $_GET after sending SMS
        $smarty->assign("contact_number_enc", $_GET['contact_number']);
        $smarty->assign("contact_name_enc", $_GET['contact_name']);


        $smarty->display('templates/conversation_body.tpl');
    }
}
else
{
    $smarty->display('templates/login_body.tpl');
}
```